# "Rough" extrusion or outline

Tags: materials, objects

I'm trying to understand how the following material / object can be created in Blender, particular the "inset" inside the plastic that roughly follows the shape of the character.

How would I start with creating such an outline?

[image]

Comment: Could probably do something with the shrinkwrap modifier, then smooth with sculpt tools

Comment: You could trace the outline with a grease pencil stroke to get the general shape in silouette.Then convert the grease pencil object to a mesh object. Then you can go into edit mode and extrude the mesh object to give it depth. Then cap the ends of this new object with the grid fill tool, so as to keep your mesh all quads, even with the caps.Then throw on a Subdivsion Surface modifier to round out the corners.

Comment: As I think about it now, the easiest way might actually be to use Sculpt mode on a subdivided plane. You might have trouble getting and keeping the walls of the pocket flat, though.